# Upload a local file via Facebook API in Android

Tags: android, facebook, url, checkin

I'm trying to get a URL of a local image file in Android Gallery. I've tried formats like

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/test.jpg
```

or like

```
content://media/external/images/media/1
```

but none of them works. I'm just wondering if anyone can give me a properly formatted Android  local file URL example? I need this to upload photo while checking in using Facebook api. thank you very much

Comment: Your format is right. What problem do you get?

Comment: thank you @Jett Hsieh   and  Earl  my error(response from facebook) is "08-09 11:39:04.812: DEBUG/onComplete(3117): {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#100) picture URL is not properly formatted"}}
"

Comment: I am not familiar with FB API. But I think what it needs is real URL, which starts with "http", not an URI in the local device.

Comment: @Jett Hesieh  Yea that's exactly what I'm thinking about... but I know we can use something like "file:\\\" to represent a local file in URL way in computers so just trying if this would be still work on android... thank you very much though

Comment: file:///mnt/sdcard/test.jpg is correct, try it in Browser

Comment: This question is badly titled; the provided local file URL is correct, but Facebook API can't work with it (the accepted answers explains why). I fixed the title, as this question doesn't help those who wonder about Android file URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook API can't use your local file URI as it doesn't have access to the contents of your phone. You need to use a POST request to physically upload the contents of your file.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken UNIX paths go like this:

```
/mnt/sdcard/test.jpg
```

Comment: @sightofnick Hi thank you for your answer. This was the first thing I tried, and got a response of "picture URL is not properly formatted".

Answer (score 0):

**Absolute Path**
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() gives to absolute path to SDCard. 
From here "/DCIM/Camera/" would give you the path to folder used by Camera to store captured image.

So your file path would be something like this

```
String mBaseFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
String filePath = mBaseFolderPath  + "test.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
```

**Content Resolver Path**
content://media/external/images/media/1  is the path referred by content resolver. This is like 
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI + Image Id

If you get hold of Uri of the image then you can use the following to get bitmap correspondong to the image.

```
Bitmap someBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), url);
```

Shash

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I tried both of them but failed. got the same response of " picture URL is not properly formatted"